# What is even meant by the "cardinality of a model?"

Tags: terminology, model-theory

Please help me understand even the most basic ideas in model theory:

When in model theory we speak of the cardinality of a model, what exactly is meant by that? I assume that when we say that the model $M$ has cardinality $\kappa$, then $\kappa$ is a cardinal number, and there is a bijection from $\kappa$ ot $M$. But a bijection *where*? In what system? In an extension model? How can these terms make any sense except *inside* a model?

Also, is it necessarily the case that $M$ is even in one-to-one correspondence with any cardinal number? Because at least *inside* a model $M$ for **ZFC**, the number of elements in $M$ exceeds any cardinal number.

Comment: In model theory, a model $\mathcal M=(M,\dots)$ consists of a set $M$, and some underlying relations, functions, and distinguished elements. The cardinality of the model $\mathcal M$ is the set-theoretic cardinality of $M$, as computed in the universe of all sets.

Comment: Okay, so we work with a super-universe of all sets outside any model?

Comment: Yes, model theory takes place within the universe of all sets.

Comment: But isn't such a universe a gigantic problem? First of all, how do we decide which sets exist in this universe? We have to avoid hitting Russell, for instance. But you say that the universe is "set-theoretic;" do you mean that this universe is itself supposed to be a model for **ZFC**? In that case, this universe should have a cardinality inside itself.

Comment: Sorry if my questions are extremely elementary.

Comment: "But isn't such a universe a gigantic problem?" No, it isn't. (And you are not working in a *model* of $\mathsf{ZFC}$, but in the actual universe of sets. If for some reason you actually want to work relative to such a model, of course everything is relativized in that case, including what is meant by "model".)

Comment: You have known for a long time what the cardinality of a group means. There is nothing different in general. Model Theory is like any other branch of mathematics, say Analytic Number Theory, or Numerical Analysis.

Comment: Just think of yourself as working in some nice canonical model, and the only objects you need to worry about are inside this model.

Comment: (Incidentally, this sort of question is part of the reason I object to the "truth only makes sense with respect to some model" tack I see some people take when introducing logic. It can make this sort of issue very tricky to untangle if not presented clearly, because it makes it hard to talk about the truth of statements in the metalanguage.)

Comment: So, if I understand you correctly, what Skolem's paradox actually states is this: Let $(M,\in)$ be a model for **ZFC**. Then there exists a countable set $N$ in $M$ (i.e. $N$ is really a *set* in the model $M$, and there exists a bijection $\Bbb N\to N$ *inside* $M$) such that $(N,{\in}\big|_N)$ is a model for **ZFC**. Here ${\in}\big|_N$ is the restriction of $\in$ to $N$. Is this correct?

Comment: @Gaussler: No. Skolem's theorem (in its basic form, at least) says nothing about the "smaller model" being a set in the "larger model" (nor does it even refer to models of set theory in particular). I think it is not even possible (due to elementarity) but I'd have to think about it.

Comment: @Gaussler: No. It is not a theorem that every model of ZFC contains a model of ZFC; otherwise ZFC would  prove Con(ZFC)! It certainly says nothing about the $\in$ relation of a model being a restriction of the $\in$ relation of the ambient universe. Skolem's "paradox" is that *if* there's a model of set theory, there's another, countable model of set theory which, *relative to its own $\in$ relation and internal cardinals*, sees itself as containing uncountable sets.

Comment: @MaliceVidrine, okay, but what does it really mean that the model is countable? Is countable an absolute property? Does "countable" make any sense if we are not *inside* another model? If there is a one-to-one correspondence between $\Bbb N$ and the elements of the model, *where* is this one-to-one correspondence? In what universe does it live?

Comment: Pick one. They all satisfy the theorems of ZFC. You could ask the same question about any model I tried to offer you: "what model is that model in, with which membership relation". You can't talk about a model in the first place except as a model in some set theoretic universe.

Comment: And while countability isn't absolute in the sense that it can be realized in some model differently, "is countable" is a property that can be formulated in FoL irrespective of model. The same way we can talk about conjugation without specifying a group.